# Axios Request Aborted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

I have an axios post request which gets triggered when we click on button. But as soon as button is clicked it shows this error and page reloads

[image]

The function on which the request is getting triggered

```
const handleForm = async (e) => {
//Check username is unique
e.preventDefault();
const oldUserName = await doesUserNameExist(userName);
if (oldUserName) {
  activeUser.displayName = userName;
  const imgUrl = await uploadPhoto(activeUser?.displayName, profilePicture);
  const userFormData = {
    userName,
    bio,
    gender,
    age,
    uid: activeUser.uid,
    emailAddress: activeUser.email,
    accountCreatedOn: serverTimestamp(),
    lastSeen: serverTimestamp(),
    following: [''],
    followers: [''],
    role: 'user',
    status: '',
    photoURL: imgUrl ? imgUrl : activeUser?.photoURL,
  };

  //  await addUser(userFormData);
  const nodeData = {
    id: activeUser.uid,
    emailAddress: activeUser.email,
    userName,
  };
  await axios.post('path_to_api/api/user', nodeData, {
    headers: nodeData,
  }); 
}
```

Please Help. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why you are put data in headers ?

Comment: As there is middleware to authenticate the same data that is passed with cookie

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 await axios.post('path_to_api/api/user', nodeData);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work..

Comment: hey
your button that trigger the function is in type="submit" or  type="button" ?

Comment: tried both doesn't work either